# Cant create a foreign key for a table that has two primary keys set

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ddl

I am trying to create a foreign key pointed from one table to another. these being `tbl_inventory` and `tbl_player`. The player table has two primary keys set, `player_score` and `playerID`. When I try to create a foreign key within the inventory table to get the playerID. it throws the error below:
[image]

Here is my SQL script:

```
drop database if exists example_db;
create database example_db;
use example_db;


/*Player  ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_player; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_player` (
    `player_score` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `playerID` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10375 PRIMARY KEY (`player_score`,`playerID`)
);

/*Inventory ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_inventory;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_inventory` (
    `inventoryID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `playerID` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10520 PRIMARY KEY (`inventoryID`),
        FOREIGN KEY (playerID) REFERENCES tbl_player(playerID)
);
```

I did some troubleshooting and found that it works when I only define one primary key, but two are required for the project that I am working on. Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: The player table has _one_ primary key, which consists of two columns.

Comment: A foreign key must reference the whole primary key - i.e. both columns here.

Comment: 'In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: You need to reference both columns of the primary key

Comment: @jarth - don't think so https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fgnCCLdUgxZhycc1awSqKp/0 - as long as primary key has playerid as first node tbl_inventory will be created

Comment: @P.Salmon, amazing. I wouldn't build my systems depending on that weird behavior. (Remember the MySQL GROUP BY history.)

Comment: What is the purpose of tbl_player? It seems to hold multiple unigue scores per player with no reference to what the scores are for

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (playerID) REFERENCES tbl_player(playerID)` needs to exist an index in `tbl_player` where `playerID` column is a prefix. Either create such index or swap columns in primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a composite primary key, so you need a composite foreign key:

```
/*Inventory ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_inventory;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_inventory` (
    `inventoryID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `playerID` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `player_score` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10520 PRIMARY KEY (`inventoryID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (player_score,playerID) REFERENCES tbl_player(player_score,playerID)
);
```

Also you can may be try having one primary key and the other column as unique : (only if it works for your project to have single column of table as primary and other as unique)

```
/*Player  ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_player; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_player` (
    `player_score` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `playerID` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10375 PRIMARY KEY (`playerID`),
    UNIQUE(`player_score`)
);

/*Inventory ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_inventory;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_inventory` (
    `inventoryID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `playerID` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10520 PRIMARY KEY (`inventoryID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (playerID) REFERENCES tbl_player(playerID)
);
```

Cheers!!